# Type problem with generic object argument

Tags: java, generics

I have an abstract class,

```
public abstract class WebserviceIntegration {
    //...
}
```

which is used in many classes, like this

```
public class Manager extends WebserviceIntegration {
    //...
}
```

Now I've built a class, that gets as generic argument the abstract class as `F` argument, that has a method inside of it:

```
public class NewUserWindow<T, F extends WebserviceIntegration> extends Window {

    public NewUserWindow(T objOne, F objTwo) {
        //...
        saveConnectedBean(objTwo); //no problems here
    }

    public void saveConnectedBean(F bean) throws MyException{
        //...
    }
}
```

Ofc everything is fine if I create a new window `NewUserWindow<?, Manager> window = new NewUserWindow<>(new OtherClass(), new Manager());` and i save the bean passed to the window.

Now what I wanna do is saving a **new** `Manager` inside the constructor:

```
public NewUserWindow(T objOne, F objTwo) {
        //...

        Manager manager = new Manager();
        //... setting manager stuff

        saveConnectedBean(manager); //does not compile
 }
```

The compiler now stopping me saying that `saveConnectedBean(F) in NewUserWindow cannot be applied to (my.package.path.Manager)`.
 
If I change that with

```
saveConnectedBean((F)manager);
```

It compiles, but warns me that the cast is unchecked.

1. In the first case, why the compiler is not aware that my `Manager` class is extending `WebserviceIntegration`, which makes it compatibile with `F` class?
2. In the second case, how can I make a safe cast? I can't check with `manager instanceof F`, so how can I do?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure to understand `window.saveConnectedBean(manager)`should work, Are you creating a new method in the class NewUserWindow to save a new Manager ?

Comment: @MatthieuGabin edited the question: that happens inside the constructor

Comment: May the downvoters say why are they downvoting?

Comment: i didn't downvote but the fact that you was not precise in the place where the invocation fails for the compiler makes the question unclear.

Comment: I have edited the question with a context of invocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not very clear but according to your issue I suppose that the code that fails is located in the constructor of the generic class.

1) The compiler considers your invocation regarding the `F`declaration as inside the generic class the compiler doesn't know the exact type of `F`. Don't forget that generics are just compilation artifacts.
So if inside the constructor you instantiate your `Manager` variable such as :

```
Manager manager = new Manager();
```

but you declared your generic type such as `NewUserWindow<?, OtherSubClass> window = ...` 
it will break the type safety.

2) Avoid `instanceof` in generic class. It defeats the generic purpose in a some way.

As alternative you should pass the `Manager` from the client side of the generic instance such as :

```
Manager manager = new Manager();
NewUserWindow<?, Manager> newUserWindow = new NewUserWindow<>(new ..., manager);
newUserWindow.saveConnectedBean(manager);
```

From your comment :

> Let's say I can't run across solution 2, is there any other way for
>   safe casting?

You could do that by doing `NewUserWindow` an abstract class that declare as abstract a method that returns `F`.

```
public abstract class NewUserWindow<T, F extends WebserviceIntegration> extends Window {

    public NewUserWindow(T objOne, F objTwo) {

        F f = createF();
        saveConnectedBean(f);
    }

    public abstract F createF();

    public void saveConnectedBean(F bean) throws MyException{
        //...
    }
}
```

And implement it such as :

```
public ManagerUserWindow extends NewUserWindow<T, Manager> extends Window {

    public Manager createF(){
       return new Manager();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing, I've edited the question: yes, it's inside the constructor.

Comment: Let's say I can't run across solution 2, is there any other way for safe casting?

Comment: Never as it could never be safe. You could bypass the problem by creating a subclass of the generic class for each supplier type : `OtherSubClass`,  I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

1) It's not compiling since you only know that F type is extended WebserviceIntegration but it could be any type that extend WebserviceIntegration

So if you have an other class that extend WebserviceIntegration like

```
public class NoManager extends WebserviceIntegration {
  //...
}
```

And you create an other `NewUserWindow<?, NoManager> noManagerWindow = new NewUserWindow<>(new OtherClass(), new NoManager())` you can't do something like `noManagerWindow.saveConnectedBean(new Manager())`

2) You should not do a cast since you can't be sure F is Type of Manager.

I think what you want to do is just use the type WebserviceIntegration and not using any generic.

Comment: Thanks, the point 1 cleared my doubts. For point 2, it's not working because I cant change my parameter to `WebserviceIntegration`. Any other ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that. Add abstract `save` method into `WebserviceIntegration`

```
public static abstract class WebserviceIntegration {
    public abstract void save();
}
```

Implement this method in each subclass of `WebserviceIntegration`

```
public static class Manager extends WebserviceIntegration {
    @Override
    public void save() { // saving Manager here }
}
```

So `saveConnectedBean` can now accept `WebserviceIntegration`

```
public void saveConnectedBean(WebserviceIntegration bean) { }
```

It should be safe as each subtype of `WebserviceIntegration` have to implement `save` functionality.

---

As an alternative, you can introduce new method type parameter

```
public <B extends WebserviceIntegration> void saveConnectedBean(B bean) { }
```

In this case `saveConnectedBean` is restricted to be implemented only with methods from `WebserviceIntegration` as actual subtype isn't known.